Error code 0x800705b4 during device preparation for Entra/Intune
I am trying to set up a Windows 11 Pro PC via Intune/Entra. My procedure was as follows:
Start the PC with a generic Microsoft account. Perform all updates.
Then, do a clean install using the cloud installation.
After the installation, add the PC to Intune/Entra via Autopilot using CMD with the following commands:
Powershell.exe -Executionpolicy Bypass
Install-Script -name get-WindowsAutopilotinfo -Force
Set-Executionpolicy -scope Process -Executionpolicy
Remotesigned Get-Windowsautopilotinfo -online
In the following pop-up I logged in via Admin account and thus added the device. Then followed the installation steps and logged in with the user who will use the device. Now, at the first step "Device preparation" and the sub-step "Secure your hardware," I get the error code "0x800705b4".
enter image description here
Whatever I do, complete new installs, rolling back updates, etc., I immediately return to the screen where the device is being set up for work or school. I don't log in here. TPM2.0 is enabled and I have already set up more than 10 similar devices in exactly the same way. Also tried sfc /scannow via CMD. How can I restore the device so that it does not immediately come back into Intune/Entra or can I resolve the error code?

Solved, remove the device from intune and autopilot completely and restart.
